# Is there a way to detect default images folder via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like that in my webpage the user would be able to upload images.

When the user clicks on a particular `div`, `image`, `button` or whatever, a `Browse Dialog` will be open. Similar to this:

```js
document.getElementById('buttonFile').onclick = function(){
 document.getElementById("file").click();
}
```

```css
#file{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file">
<button id="buttonFile" type="button">Open File Dialog</button>
```

But the default folder where the images usually are stored usually change between OS and languages. I would like that on this `Browse Dialog` the default images folder will be open, regardless of the OS or the language.

For example, on my `Windows 10` on `English` it is stored on `This PC` named as `Pictures`.

Is there a way to open the `Browse Dialog` always on the default images folder?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: not possible for security reasons you can't read it from browser

Comment: I don't think it's credible to assume that "My Pictures" (for ex.) is the most convenient place to start the search for your image for most users

Comment: I'd be surprsied if that works somehow, but  i'm curious now too!

Comment: oh you can open the explorer, but it won't default to the images folder. you can also check to see if the file is an image, and for the file size in javascript

Comment: Why do you assume all operating systems have a default images folder?

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky And is there a convenient place to start the search? Or just let the Browser Window to search a folder automatically (that is usually the last folder that you have used to upload something)?

Comment: @Oriol I do not assume at all, I just wanted that if some OS has a default images folder, then load it. If not, then let the `Browser Dialog` to open a folder automatically.

Comment: the last folder you uploaded from is probably your best bet

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky Ok, thank you for your opinion :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

The page author has absolutely no influence over which directory the browse  dialog will open in.

Comment: So the best approach is to let the `Browser Dialog` to open a folder automatically? I was thinking about if some OS has a default images folder, then load it (I did not know if it is possible) and if not, let the `Browser Dialog` to open a folder automatically.

Comment: "So the best approach is to let the Browser Dialog to open a folder automatically?" — Best and **only**.

Comment: "I was thinking about if some OS has a default images folder, then load it (I did not know if it is possible)" — As this answer says, it isn't possible.

Comment: It is why I put I did not know. Because now I know it is impossible :)